# Keep the active value of Radioslider jquery plugin when the page is refreshed/reloaded

Tags: html, jquery

I am using the code below to covert my radio buttons into slider range with the help of the Radioslider jquery plugin I found [here](https://tcharlss.github.io/radioslider/#/?id=radioslider). My problem is that when i refresh/reload the page is losing the selected value and goes at the default checked radio button. Is there any way to keep the new selected value after the page is refreshed??

```js
!function($){"use strict";var a="radioslider",s=0,e={size:"",animation:!0,isDisabledd:!1,fillOffset:null,fillOrigin:null,fit:!1,onSelect:null,orientation:"horizontal",sliderClass:"radioslider",itemClass:"radioslider__item",inputClass:"radioslider__input",labelClass:"radioslider__label",dotClass:"radioslider__dot",textClass:"radioslider__text",barClass:"radioslider__bar",fillClass:"radioslider__fill",handleClass:"radioslider__handle",horizontalClass:"radioslider_horizontal",verticalClass:"radioslider_vertical",fitClass:"radioslider_fit",animationClass:"radioslider_animated",dotUnderClass:"under",inverseClass:"inverse",activeClass:"active",focusClass:"focused",disabledClass:"disabled"},n={orientation:{horizontal:{dimension:"width",direction:"left",directionStyle:"left",coordinate:"x"},vertical:{dimension:"height",direction:"top",directionStyle:"bottom",coordinate:"y"}}};function l(i,t){s++,this.$window=$(window),this.$document=$(document),this.$bearer=$(i),this.options=$.extend({},e,t,this.$bearer.data()),this.orientation=this.options.orientation,this.DIMENSION=n.orientation[this.orientation].dimension,this.DIRECTION=n.orientation[this.orientation].direction,this.DIRECTION_STYLE=n.orientation[this.orientation].directionStyle,this.COORDINATE=n.orientation[this.orientation].coordinate,this.number=s,this.identifier=a+"-"+s,this.level=0,this.value=null,this.levelsCount=this.$bearer.find("input[type=radio]").length,this.$bar=$('<span class="'+this.options.barClass+'">'),this.$fill=$('<span class="'+this.options.fillClass+'">'),this.$handle=$('<span class="'+this.options.handleClass+'">'),this.$bar.append(this.$fill.css("visibility","hidden")).append(this.$handle),this.init()}l.prototype.init=function(){this.activate(),this.onInit&&"function"==typeof this.onInit&&this.onInit()},l.prototype.activate=function(){this.addBase(),this.setSlider(),this.addInteraction(),this.options.isDisabledd&&this.setDisabled()},l.prototype.addBase=function(){var i,l,t,s,o=this.options,e=this.$bearer,a=this.$bar;e.addClass(o.sliderClass+" "+o[this.orientation+"Class"]+" "+(o.fit?o.fitClass:"")+" "+(o.animation?o.animationClass:"")+" "+(o.size?o.sliderClass+"_"+o.size:"")).attr("data-radioslider",this.number),l=e.find("> input[type=radio]").each(function(i){$(this).addClass(o.inputClass).attr("data-level",i+1)}),this.$inputs=l,this.$inputsDisabled=this.$bearer.find("> input[type=radio][disabled]"),t=e.find("> label").each(function(i){var t,s,e,a,n;e=$(this).html(),a=$('<span class="'+o.textClass+'">').html(e),t=i+1,s=l.filter("[data-level="+t+"]").attr("value"),n=$('<span class="'+o.dotClass+'">').attr("data-level",t).attr("data-value",s),$(this).addClass(o.labelClass).html("").append(n).append(a)}),s=e.find("."+o.dotClass),this.$dots=s,this.$labels=t,l.each(function(){var i=$('<div class="'+o.itemClass+'">');$(this).nextUntil("input").addBack().wrapAll(i),"disabled"===$(this).attr("disabled")&&$(this).parent().addClass(o.disabledClass)}),i=e.find("."+o.itemClass),this.$items=i,"vertical"===this.orientation&&i.each(function(i,t){e.prepend(t)}),e.append(a)},l.prototype.setSlider=function(){var i=this.$inputs.filter(":checked");if(0<i.length){var t,s,a,n,l,o,e,r,d,h,c,u=this.options,p=this.$inputs,f=this.$bar,C=this.$fill,v=this.$handle,m=u.fillOrigin,b=u.fillOffset;if(i.next("."+u.labelClass).addClass(u.activeClass).parents("."+u.itemClass).addClass(u.activeClass),p.not(i).next("."+u.labelClass).removeClass(u.activeClass).parents("."+u.itemClass).removeClass(u.activeClass),a=Number(i.attr("data-level")),s=this.getValueFromLevel(a),e=this.getPositionFromValue(s),d=this.getBarOffset(),null!==m&&(r=this.getPositionFromValue(m))||null!==b&&(r=this.getPositionFromValue(b)))if(n=null!==m?this.getLevelFromValue(m):this.getLevelFromValue(b),C.css("opacity","").addClass("offseted"),this.$handleOrigin?t=this.$handleOrigin:(t=$('<span class="'+this.options.handleClass+" "+u.handleClass+'_origin">'),this.$handleOrigin=t,C.after(t),t[0].style[this.DIRECTION_STYLE]=this.dimensionToPercent(r)+"%"),n<=a)switch(f.removeClass(u.inverseClass),t.removeClass(u.inverseClass).css("opacity",""),this.orientation){case"horizontal":case"vertical":h=e-r,c=r}else if(null!==m)switch(f.addClass(u.inverseClass),t.addClass(u.inverseClass),this.orientation){case"horizontal":h=r-e,c=e;break;case"vertical":h=r+e,c=e}else t.css("opacity",0),C.css("opacity",0),h=2*d,c=e;else h=e,c=0;C.css("visibility",""),C[0].style[this.DIRECTION_STYLE]=this.dimensionToPercent(c)+"%","vertical"===this.orientation?(C[0].style[this.DIMENSION]=100-this.dimensionToPercent(h)+"%",v[0].style[this.DIRECTION_STYLE]=100-this.dimensionToPercent(e)+"%"):(C[0].style[this.DIMENSION]=this.dimensionToPercent(h)+"%",v[0].style[this.DIRECTION_STYLE]=this.dimensionToPercent(e)+"%"),this.level=a,this.value=s,0,l=n?Math.min(n,a):1,o=n?Math.max(n,a):a,p.each(function(){0;var i=$(this),t=i.next("label").find("."+u.dotClass),s=Number(i.attr("data-level")),e=null!==b&&a<n;s===a?t.css("opacity","0"):s<l||o<s||e?t.css("opacity","").removeClass(u.dotUnderClass):t.css("opacity","").addClass(u.dotUnderClass)})}},l.prototype.addInteraction=function(){var i=this,t=this.$bearer,s=this.$inputs,e=this.$handle;s.on("change."+i.identifier,function(){$(this).prop("checked",!0),i.options.onSelect&&i.options.onSelect($(this),[s]),i.setSlider(),t.trigger("radiochange",{origin:i.identifier})}).on("focusin."+i.identifier,function(){e.addClass(i.options.focusClass)}).on("focusout."+i.identifier,function(){e.removeClass(i.options.focusClass)})},l.prototype.setDisabled=function(i){this.options.isDisabled=!0;var t=this.$bearer,s=this.$labels,e=this.$inputs,a=this.options.disabledClass;$.merge(s,e).each(function(){$(this).off("click change")}),e.each(function(){$(this).prop("disabled",!0).parent().addClass(a)}),"function"==typeof i&&i(s,e),t.addClass(a).trigger("radiodisabled",{origin:this.identifier})},l.prototype.setEnabled=function(i){this.options.isDisabled=!1;var t=this,s=t.$bearer,e=t.$labels,a=t.$inputs,n=t.options.disabledClass;a.not(t.$inputsDisabled).each(function(){$(this).prop("disabled",!1).parent().removeClass(n)}),t.addInteraction(),"function"==typeof i&&i(e,a),s.trigger("radiodenabled",{origin:this.identifier}).removeClass(n)},l.prototype.getValue=function(){return this.value},l.prototype.setValue=function(i){i!==this.value&&this.$inputs.filter("[value="+i+"]").trigger("click",{origin:this.identifier})},l.prototype.getLevelFromValue=function(i){var t;return t=Number(this.$inputs.filter('[value="'+i+'"]').attr("data-level")),t=Number.isNaN(t)?0:t},l.prototype.getValueFromLevel=function(i){return this.$inputs.filter("[data-level="+i+"]").attr("value")},l.prototype.getPositionFromValue=function(i){var t,s,e;return(e=this.$dots.filter('[data-value="'+i+'"]'))&&0<e.length&&(s={width:e.outerWidth(),height:e.outerHeight()}[this.DIMENSION],t=e.position()[this.DIRECTION]+s/2),t=Number.isNaN(t)?0:t},l.prototype.getBarOffset=function(){var i;return i={width:this.$bar.outerHeight(),height:this.$bar.outerWidth()}[this.DIMENSION]/2,i=Number.isNaN(i)?0:i},l.prototype.dimensionToPercent=function(i){return 100*i/{width:this.$bearer.outerWidth(),height:this.$bearer.outerHeight()}[this.DIMENSION]},l.prototype.destroy=function(){var s=this.options;this.$document.off("."+this.identifier),this.$window.off("."+this.identifier),this.$bearer.off("."+this.identifier).removeData("plugin_"+a),this.$inputs.off("."+this.identifier),this.$bearer.removeAttr("data-radioslider").removeClass(s.sliderClass+" "+s[this.orientation+"Class"]+" "+s.fitClass+" "+s.animationClass+" "+s.sliderClass+"_"+s.size),this.$dots.remove(),this.$bar.remove(),this.$items.children().unwrap().each(function(){var i,t=$(this);t.removeAttr("data-level").removeClass(s.inputClass+" "+s.labelClass+" "+s.textClass),0<this.children.length&&(i=t.children().html(),t.children().remove(),t.html(i))}),this.$bearer.find('[class=""]').removeAttr("class")},$.fn[a]=function(s){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return this.each(function(){var i=$(this),t=i.data("plugin_"+a);t||i.data("plugin_"+a,t=new l(this,s)),"string"==typeof s&&t[s].apply(t,e)})}}(jQuery);
 
 $("#distance").radioslider({
        size: "small",
        fit: true
    });
```

```css
.radioslider,
.radioslider * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.radioslider:before, .radioslider:after,
.radioslider *:before,
.radioslider *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radioslider {
  /* Color variables */
  --bar-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  --fill-color: #3377ff;
  --fill-color-inverse: #e6664d;
  --handle-color: white;
  /* Default size variables */
  --dot-size: 1.5em;
  --bar-padding: 0.25em;
  --bar-margin-bottom: 1em;
  --bar-thickness: calc(var(--bar-padding)*2 + var(--dot-size));
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.25em;
  padding: var(--bar-padding);
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  /* ========================
     Options, inputs & labels
     ======================== */
  /* =================
     Bar + fill + handle
     ================= */
  /* ==========
     Horizontal
     ========== */
  /* ========
     Vertical
     ======== */
  /* ========
     Animated
     ======== */
  /* ========
     Disabled
     ======== */
  /* ===========
     Fit borders
     =========== */
  /* ============
     Size : small
     ============ */
  /* ===========
      Size : tiny
      =========== */
}
.radioslider__item {
  z-index: 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
}
.radioslider__input:checked + .radioslider__label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.radioslider__input:checked + .radioslider__label .radioslider__dot {
  background-color: white;
  background-color: var(--handle-color);
}
.radioslider__label {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radioslider__label:hover .radioslider__dot, .radioslider__label:focus .radioslider__dot, .radioslider__label:focus-within .radioslider__dot {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
          box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}
.radioslider__label:hover .radioslider__dot.under, .radioslider__label:focus .radioslider__dot.under, .radioslider__label:focus-within .radioslider__dot.under {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radioslider__dot {
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: var(--dot-size);
  height: var(--dot-size);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 99em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.radioslider__dot.under {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.radioslider__text {
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  /* better than word-break, when supported */
  text-align: center;
}
.radioslider__bar {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: var(--bar-color);
}
.radioslider__bar.inverse .radioslider__fill {
  background-color: #e6664d;
  background-color: var(--fill-color-inverse);
}
.radioslider__bar.inverse .radioslider__handle {
  border-color: #e6664d;
  border-color: var(--fill-color-inverse);
}
.radioslider__fill {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3377ff;
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
}
.radioslider__fill.offseted.offseted {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.radioslider__handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
  background-color: white;
  background-color: var(--handle-color);
  border-radius: 99em;
  border: 0.2em solid var(--fill-color);
}
.radioslider__handle_origin {
  background-color: var(--fill-color);
}
.radioslider__handle_origin.inverse {
  background-color: var(--fill-color-inverse);
}
.radioslider__handle.focused.focused {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
          box-shadow: 0 0 0.4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}
.radioslider_horizontal {
  -ms-flex-flow: row;
      flex-flow: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__item {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 0px;
      flex: 1 0 0px;
  /* 0px flex basis to force equal widths */
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__label {
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
      flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__text {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  margin-top: calc(var(--bar-padding) + var(--bar-margin-bottom));
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__bar {
  height: 2em;
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__handle {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__fill {
  border-top-left-radius: 99em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 99em;
  height: 100%;
}
.radioslider_vertical {
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
      flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
      align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__item {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__item:last-of-type {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__label {
  -ms-flex-flow: row;
      flex-flow: row;
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__text {
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  margin-left: calc(var(--bar-padding) + var(--bar-margin-bottom));
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__bar {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2em;
  width: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__handle {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
          transform: translateY(50%);
}
.radioslider_vertical .radioslider__fill {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 99em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 99em;
}
.radioslider_animated .radioslider__fill,
.radioslider_animated .radioslider__handle {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.radioslider.disabled {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(90);
          filter: grayscale(90);
}
.radioslider.disabled .radioslider__item,
.radioslider .radioslider__item.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.radioslider.disabled .radioslider__item .radioslider__label,
.radioslider.disabled .radioslider__item .radioslider__input,
.radioslider .radioslider__item.disabled .radioslider__label,
.radioslider .radioslider__item.disabled .radioslider__input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.radioslider.disabled .radioslider__item .radioslider__text,
.radioslider .radioslider__item.disabled .radioslider__text {
  opacity: 0.33;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.radioslider_fit .radioslider__item {
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
      flex-grow: 0;
}
.radioslider_fit .radioslider__text {
  width: 400%;
}
.radioslider_small {
  --dot-size: 0.7em;
  --bar-padding: 0.15em;
  --bar-margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.radioslider_small .radioslider__dot {
  width: 0.7em;
  height: 0.7em;
  width: var(--dot-size);
  height: var(--dot-size);
}
.radioslider_small .radioslider__text {
  margin-top: 1.15em;
  margin-top: calc(var(--bar-padding) + var(--bar-margin-bottom));
}
.radioslider_small .radioslider__bar {
  height: 1em;
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_small .radioslider__handle {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  width: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_tiny {
  --dot-size: 0.2em;
  --bar-padding: 0.1em;
  --bar-margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__dot {
  position: relative;
  width: 0.2em;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: var(--dot-size);
  height: var(--dot-size);
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__dot:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  right: -1em;
  bottom: -1em;
  left: -1em;
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__text {
  margin-top: 1.1em;
  margin-top: calc(var(--bar-padding) + var(--bar-margin-bottom));
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__bar {
  height: 0.4em;
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__handle {
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  width: calc((var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2)) * 4);
  height: calc((var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2)) * 4);
}
.radioslider_tiny .radioslider__handle_origin {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
  height: calc(var(--dot-size) + (var(--bar-padding) * 2));
}
.radioslider_tiny.radioslider_horizontal .radioslider__handle {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% + (var(--bar-thickness)/2)));
          transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% + (var(--bar-thickness)/2)));
}

/* Accessible method to hide content */
.visually-hidden, .radioslider__input {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
  height: auto;
  /* new - was 1px */
  margin: 0;
  /* new - was -1px */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* 1 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="distance" class="" role="radiogroup"><input id="distance5" type="radio" name="distance" value="5"><label for="distance5">5 km </label>
<input id="distance10" type="radio" name="distance" value="10"><label for="distance10">10 km </label>
<input id="distance50" type="radio" name="distance" value="50" checked=""><label for="distance50">50 km </label>
<input id="distance100" type="radio" name="distance" value="100" ><label for="distance100">100 km </label>
<input id="distance0" type="radio" name="distance" value="0"><label for="distance0"> Max </label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

As you probably have already been told, whenever a webpage reloads, the content reverts back to it's original state.

**Solution**

We will use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the value of the checked radio button whenever a ["change" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) happens which also invokes `saveData(e)`. The event handler for ["DOMContentLoaded" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) is `loadData(e)`.

***The Web Storage API is prohibited to function in SO Snippets. If you want to review a working example go to: [<kbd>Plunker</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/WCWOLUl81ibijbSY?open=lib%2Fscript.js)***<sup>❇</sup>

*Details are commeted in the example below*

```js
// Define tag (key)
let tag = `dist`;
/*
Utility function gets data from localStorage 
referenced by key
*/
const getLS = (key) => localStorage.getItem(key) || null;
/*
Utility function sets data to localStorage referenced by key
*/
const setLS = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, data);
/*
When the DOM is loaded, function loadData(e) is invoked. 
When any descendant tag of form changes saveData(e) is invoked.
*/
$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', loadData);
$('form').on('change', saveData);
// Event handler passes the Event Object
function loadData(e) {
  // Get data from the LS by key: 'dist'
  let data = getLS(tag);
  /*
  Go inside of form to find a tag with the value 
  equal to data then check the checkbox
  */
  $('form').find(`[value="${data}"]`).prop('checked', true);
}
// Event handler for the change event
function saveData(e) {
  // Get the tag rhe user changed
  let val = e.target.value;
  // Set >tag< with >val< to LS
  setLS(tag, val);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1 'Segoe UI';
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href='lib/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset id="distance" role="radiogroup">
      <input id="d005" type="radio" name="distance" value="5" /><label for="d005">5 km</label>
      <input id="d010" type="radio" name="distance" value="10" /><label for="d010">10 km</label>
      <input id="d050" type="radio" name="distance" value="50" /><label for="d050">50 km</label>
      <input id="d100" type="radio" name="distance" value="100" /><label for="d100">100 km</label>
      <input id="d000" type="radio" name="distance" value="0" /><label for="d000">Max</label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

<sup>❇Click the green <kbd>Preview</kbd> button. Check any radio button. Then click the refresh button in the editor toolbar or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The checked checkbox should remain after a reload.</sup>